# SQL select statement with 3 conditions if there is null value in one condition the other conditions will fails?

Tags: sql, asp.net, sql-server

I have table with three columns the first one have no nulls values in it but the other two have nulls in them I write the query blow ,so I can get data from table if one or two or all of the conditions fits but the query is not give me the result I want it's keep ignore fields with null values :

```
SELECT 
    ISNULL(IQCRM_NUM, 0) AS ASIQCRM_NUM,
    ISNULL(Full_name, 0) AS ASFull_name,
    ISNULL(Mother_Name, 0) AS Mother_Name,
    ISNULL(Date_of_Birth, 0) AS Date_of_Birth,
    ISNULL(Province_of_birth, 0) AS Province_of_birth,
    ISNULL(Job, 0) AS Job 
FROM [Criminal Main Table] 
WHERE
    (Full_name LIKE N'%' + @Full_name + N'%' OR @Full_name IS NULL) AND (Mother_Name LIKE N'%' + @Mother_Name + N'%' OR @Mother_Name IS NULL) AND (Date_of_Birth LIKE N'%' + @Date_of_Birth + N'%' OR @Date_of_Birth IS NULL)
```

I want query to get data from table if any condition fit regardless
of null value like that

if I enter full_name like (`ali`) I want to get data like

```
full_name |Mother_Name |Date_of_Birth 
ali       | huda       |NULL
ali       |NULL        |1990
ali       |NULL        |NULL
ali       |Noor        |1988
```

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I get only 266 record of 10,000 if I entered % for all parameters the records with non-null values come back from table

Comment: What output do you really want?  The current `WHERE` clause seems pointless to me.

Comment: I want if I entered text in one parameter or two or all of them to filter data and get the result I want

Comment: Is the variable `@Full_Name` one of the parameters?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I want to filter data based on the passed parameter until if I the columns have null values I want to be able to get the data according to other conditions

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen yes it's

Comment: I gave you an answer below.

Comment: This is a dynamic query. the birthdate is passed as a string. Make sure it is in the right format, otherwise your query seems correct to me. you may add option recompile.

Comment: @AhmedSaeed احمد هذا الحقل هو نص اخي

Comment: is the problem, your are not getting records or in the displayed null fields?

Comment: اخي احمد لدي جدول به اسماء كثيرة ومثلا لو كتبت احمد كاسم الشخص وكانت قيمة اسم الام قيمة فارغة (NULL) فان القيد لايعرض لدي في الكرد فيو وانا استخدم ثلاثة شروط للبحث

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Are u there?

Comment: I updated my answer again.  I can read Arabic, but no else here likely can so you should use English.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen ok bro sorry for that I will try it again thanks for all ur efforts

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to build your `LIKE` conditions correctly.  The variables should appear in the predicates of the `LIKE`:

```
WHERE (Full_name LIKE '%' + @Full_name + '%' OR Full_name IS NULL) AND
      (Mother_Name LIKE '%' + @Mother_Name + '%' OR Mother_Name IS NULL) AND
      (Date_of_Birth LIKE '%' + @Date_of_Birth + '%' OR Date_of_Birth IS NULL)
```

Comment: Biegelesien Its give error The concat function required two argument ?

Comment: What is the error?  The `WHERE` clause above looks OK to me.

Comment: I try it again And it's give me the same error Msg 174, Level 15, State 1, Line 1
The CONCAT function requires 2 argument(s).

Comment: What version of MySQL are you using?

Comment: Sorry bro it's SQL-Server

Comment: SQL-server 2008 r2

Answer (score 0):

try this, I guess your problem is when one of you parameters has a valid value but other parameters not null and have value that is not in your table, in which case your WHERE ...AND criteria will never be true

```
declare  @table table
(
    IQCRM_NUM int, 
    Full_name nvarchar(100),
    Mother_Name nvarchar(100), 
    Date_of_Birth varchar(20),
    Province_of_birth nvarchar(30),
    Job varchar(50)
)
insert into @table values
(1, 'Ali', 'Huda', '2000-01-01', 'aaa', 'Job')
,(2, 'Ali', null, '2000-01-01', 'aaa', 'Job')
,(3, null, null, '2000-01-01', 'aaa', 'Job')
,(4, null, 'Huda', '2000-01-01', 'aaa', 'Job')
,(5, 'Ali', 'Huda', '2000-01-01', 'aaa', 'Job')

Declare @Full_name nvarchar(100)='Ali'
Declare @Mother_Name nvarchar(100)=null
Declare @Date_of_Birth nvarchar(20)=null --'2000-01-02'

SELECT 
    ISNULL(IQCRM_NUM, 0) AS ASIQCRM_NUM,
    ISNULL(Full_name, '') AS ASFull_name,
    ISNULL(Mother_Name, '') AS Mother_Name,
    ISNULL(Date_of_Birth, '') AS Date_of_Birth,
    ISNULL(Province_of_birth, '') AS Province_of_birth,
    ISNULL(Job, '') AS Job 
FROM @table 
WHERE
    (Full_name LIKE '%'+@Full_name + '%' OR @Full_name IS NULL) 
AND (Mother_Name LIKE N'%' + @Mother_Name + N'%' OR @Mother_Name IS NULL) 
AND (Date_of_Birth LIKE N'%' + @Date_of_Birth + N'%' OR @Date_of_Birth IS NULL)

option(recompile)
```

Comment: This is dynamic query, so, you may consider using option recompile  to use your indexes.